# Цвет консоли Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, цвета

Как настроить цветовую схему консоли в Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под цветовой схемой? 16 стандартных цветов или раскраску вывода ls или раскраску строки приглашения?

Comment: Вывод ls, цвет папок синий по умолчанию, на черном фоне совсем не читаемо

Comment: Тогда `man dir_colors`. В сети есть куча примеров файлика `.dir_colors`

Comment: Глянь последнюю ссылку на serverfault, там же всё есть, добавил ведь в ответ. Бекап сделай хоть какой-то, а то цвета это дело такое, вкусы могут меняться быстро

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать, просто отредактировав файл `.bashrc`, который находится в домашней директории:

```
$ sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

[По ссылке, подробная инструкция.](https://linuxthebest.net/kak-raskrasit-stroki-terminalakons/)

Но прежде чем вносить любые изменения в цветовую гамму, лучше сделать бэкап, на случай, если что-то не понравиться или через день другой захочется откатиться к стандартным настройкам.
Наберите команду для `.bashrc`:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc.backup
```

Также есть [подробная видео-инструкция из YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giAb4Ckh8BQ)

Есть вариант со сменой командной оболочки, к примеру `fish`.
Надо будет её установить дополнительно:

```
$ sudo apt install fish
```

[Домашняя страница fishshell](https://fishshell.com/)

[Изменение цвета терминала в Ubuntu Server. Источник Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/137649/changing-terminal-colors-in-ubuntu-server)

[Manpages Ubuntu dir_colors](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/dir_colors.5.html)

Comment: Менял цветовую гамму в 4-х разных системах, включая и Ubuntu Server и Debian, ничего тут сложного, просто по мануалу смотреть надо. Главное, не переборщить с "термоядерными цветами"